# Ajaxify link so that it still accesses address on click but doesn't change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, liquid

I've got a link that removes an item from a cart, except that when you click that link it redirects you to the cart with the item now removed. Is it possible to make it so that you can still click it and it still does its thing but it doesn' change the page (i.e. it doesn't send the user to the cart)?

**Note**: I'm working with Liquid on Shopify

Link:

```html
<a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" class="cart__remove">
                <small>{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</small>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible with a simple AJAX request, but can you clarify what have you tried?

Comment: @drip I tried literally nothing because the only AJAX I know and can use is the jQuery `.load()` function. I honestly had no idea how to approach this.

Comment: @opportunityr do you have jQuery included in your page ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have jQuery included try adding the following script

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('click', 'a.cart__remove', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var url = this.href;
     $.get(url, function(html){
       // here you know that the page the link was pointing to has executed
       // you might need to reload your card or parse it from the html you get here
       // because the index of the cart items has changed after removing one of them
       // and because you also need to update your shown cart to hide/remove the item that was selected

     });
  });
});
```

Comment: @opportunityr if you could post the html of your own cart i could add the code to remove the item from the html and also update the urls of the rest of the `remove` buttons.

Comment: @opportunityr ok. Let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of cart js instead for make your things work as you want. Here is the details on shopify cart js - [cart js Reference](https://cartjs.org/pages/reference#core-api-remove-item)

The best way will be to send the line item number through the CartJS.removeItem function. You can also remove a cart item by it's id using removeItemById.

It provides cart.requestComplete event listener where you can code to reload your page after remove item request is completed.

Comment: Can you recheck if your theme already included cart js or not. It must be in the assets folder of your theme. Incase you need further help - https://cartjs.org/pages/guide

Answer (score -1):

#### Yes You can do

AJAX Stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.

As the name suggests, it is used to deal with asynchronous data transfer.

For that,

Change the HTML to

```
<a onclick="removeCart('id');" class=" cart__remove "> <!--id indicates id of item as mentioned in your url //-->
    <small>{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</small>
</a>
```

Then add the JavaScript code

```
function removeCart(){
  var url = "cart/change?&quantity=0&line="+id;
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //create an XHR object constructor
  xhr.open("GET",url,true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xhr.status==200 && xhr.readyState==4){
      //Will execute if the request is success
      //Show some message to user saying that the item is removed
      //for example
      alert("Item removed");
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

You can also use HTTP POST if you want.